# nodejs express 3.0

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I have a nodejs express 2.0 application and I want to use express 3.0 within it. Tell me please which is state of express 3.0 at now and is there examples of express 3.0 applications?

I saw connect 2.0 has been released, so can I use it with express 2.0 ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Express 3.0 hasn't had any releases yet, but you can look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) and the [new features](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-3.x). Hold your horses.

Comment: @Ricardo `npm install express` now installs 3.0.0alpha

Comment: Thanks for the link Ricardo, would you make your comment an official answer?

Comment: @mihai - are you sure about that? seems to install 2.5.8 for me...

Comment: @UpTheCreek it's now 3.0.0rc1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had the same issue myself with my applications after doing `npm install express` .

TJ has upgraded version 3 and added/removed some features (better or for worse Im still ascertaining :P )

But the 2 things you need to MAKE sure to change on a default application is change:

`app.register..`

to:

`app.engine`

And to know that dynamicHelpers and helpers are no longer there. You have to use

`app.locals.use`

**Strongly** recommend reading his migration guide:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

TJ has had some of his examples updated (and in the process of updating others) which I found a good helper to picking it back up

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/